# Angular Issue with date in datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker

In my angular 4 application I am using material datepicker.
When I set the date I see correctly the date selected in the field, but when I save the date, making a Post request I see, in the parameter of the request, the wrong date, the datepicker set one day before selected date.

This is the datepicker

```
<md-form-field> <input mdInput
    [(ngModel)]="fareCalendar.startDate" name="startDate"
    [mdDatepicker]="picker"placeholder="From">
    <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
    <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
</md-form-field>
```

[image]

But this is the parameter I am sending:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both of them has the same time. One which is going in request parameter has the date in UTC as it is ending in z and the other which you are setting is in your Timezone. 
To resolve this issue you should use ng-model-options directive eg. **ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'utc' }** . You can get more info about this issue with this link [Date Picker Timezone Support](https://github.com/angular/material/pull/9410)

Comment: sorry but adding: ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'utc' } gives me this warning `Unknown attribute 'ng-model-options'.`

Comment: did you specified ng-model also? you have to use it ..`<md-datepicker ng-model="date" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'utc' }"></md-datepicker>`

Comment: `<md-form-field> <input mdInput
              [(ngModel)]="fareCalendar.startDate" name="endDate"
              [mdDatepicker]="picker" 
              placeholder="{{'farecalendar.table.dialog.labels.from'
     | translate }}">
             <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
             <md-datepicker #picker ng-model="date" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'utc' }"></md-datepicker> </md-form-field>` both ng-model and ng-model-options gives me the warnings

Comment: which version of angular-material lib. you are using?

Comment: "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154775/discussion-between-nimit-khandelwal-and-alessandro).

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. This answer is clearly wrong for Angular4 as is noted in the chat.